# Is there a bulit in method to enter text from right to left in an iOS 6 UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

For instance, if I wanted to input 12345:
       5
     45
    345
  2345
12345

I can try and create my own method to do this, but I was wondering if there is a built in way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. `NSTextAlignmentRight` will probably fit your needs:

```
[myTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

But there is also `setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft`. (Haven't tested this I'm not on my computer)

```
[myTextField setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft forRange:[myTextField textRangeFromPosition:[myTextField beginningOfDocument] toPosition:[myTextField endOfDocument]]];
```

Comment: I dont know what the second line does, but the first line does the job